# How should I handle dealing with a stream of incoming data?

Tags: design, node.js, sockets

I'm creating a NodeJS application that receives a ton of incoming financial data (prices) through Websockets, like anywhere from 1 to 5 data points per second which I would then like to send to the front end (which is built with React) as the data comes/changes. I will also have functions internally that simulate buy/sell orders which depend on the current price as well.

Originally, I was planning on using a REST API and making 1 GET request every second and using memcached to store the current price. Then, each second, I would send the current price stored in memcached to the front end through Websockets and if someone creates a buy/sell order, I would grab the current price at the top of the function and use that as the price. I'm not planning on saving the data right now but if it comes to it, I was planning on either adding it to MongoDB (Or a better DB) as the data came, or storing it in the cache and batch-inserting the data every minute or so.

Now that I've switched over from a REST API to a Websocket method, I'm wondering if my idea is still fine. When I connected the Websocket and started to log the incoming data, I was baffled at how fast it was coming which made me doubt if this could even work. Like memcached will be updated and accessed so frequently, would it just be better to hold a global variable called "Price" and update that as the data come? I have absolutely no experience in designing a system like this and I'm doing this as a personal project to learn.

Comment: 5 points a second is nothing for a modern computer.

Comment: If we answer these questions for you, where's the learning?

Comment: You don't need memcached, that is simply going to slow you down.  Use a client to receive the market data and write a websocket server to directly send messages to all clients every n seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Google "log drain". There are vendors who will consume your data - and then make the data available via queries on a web site application. If you have a lot of data it gets expensive. Some of the vendors have plans of 5 Gigs per day for free for 10 days - so get a POC going before their sales reps reach out to you.  I've never gotten so far as to try to query data through a REST API.